# Find blas calls happening under the hood when running inference

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, blas

I have a trained model saved with `tf.saved_model.save`; loaded back with `tf.saved_model.load` . Now I'd like to know what blas routines are called when I run inference on this model. I'm curious about what's going on under the hood; I would like to run the inference manually i.e. go through it step by step on my own and see if I can get the same results. When I say inference, I'm referring to the predict method `my_model.predict(new_input)`

Comment: What have you tried? What's your findings?

Comment: @Innat I have tried using scipy's [find_best_blas_type][1] method on the model parameters to see what blas calls could be happening. I doubt tensorflow is mapping them to the same routines as scipy though
[1]: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.blas.find_best_blas_type.html

Comment: If you could add minimum code, that would be nice. To observe the low-level computation in the inference time, you can try override the `predict_step` and preseve the prediction for futher investigation.

Comment: @Innat What I call inference step is calling the predict method on the model. So that would be `my_model.predict(new_input)`. I want to understand what blas or similar routines are invoked by the predict method

Comment: Check this [`predict_step`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e6784e4302c7b8cd116b74a784f4b78d60e83c26/keras/engine/training.py#L2058), which is called by `predict` method. You can try to override the `predict_step`, etc.